# Please help, how do I treat my beta for a white patch?

Tags: betta

I was recently treating my beta for cloudy eyes using Aquarian salt. He started improving but is now developing a white mark on the top of his head. I haven’t found any talent marks in his body. He still eats normally but sometimes swims erratically. I have been using bettafix and was wondering if I should add in LifeGuard All-in-one treatment? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: what are the results of your last watertest PH-AMMONIA-NITRITE,is your tank properly cycled https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your fish has got an fungal infection.

If you want to medicate your fish you need to do this in a separate tank,You will not want to use any type of medication in your main tank.

When you medicate a fish tank you will kill the nitrogen cyclus in your tank,this means you will have to cycle your tank again before you can add any fish to your tank again.

The nitrogen cyclus is what breaks down waste products in your tank,Bacteria breaks down fish food and other waste products first into ammonia(very toxic to fish)other bacteria converts ammonia to nitrite(a bit less toxic to your fish but still dangerous)other bacteria breaks down nitrite into nitrate,this is food for your plants and is only dangerous for your fish in high consentrations,you do waterchanges to keep the level of nitrate down.

To read more about the nitrogen cyclus and about how to cycle a fish tank you can take a look here https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm